# How to predict the title of news articles by using deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, text-mining, recurrent-neural-network

I'm interested in studying deep learning.
Recently, I've researched text mining using news articles dataset.

I want to extract the important one or two sentences from a body of article.
So, I mimic this problem as approximated version, that is, to find a title of article.

The training examples will be like this:
x is a collection of body of the articles, and 
y is a collection of title of the articles.

But, test examples only have x. (without y)
After training a model, I predict the title of test set, only using its body.

How can I build the model?
As beginner of deep learning, I want to have some insight or hint for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: how about trying sequence to sequence learning. basically it maps a sentence to another sentence. in your case, the input sentence is the news and the output one is the title.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adapt the architecture for [image captioning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4555.pdf) which uses a CNN for input analysis feeding a RNN for language generation.

For your title generation application, think of it as document captioning instead of image captioning and train a [Recurrent CNN](http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/cip/~liukang/liukangPageFile/Recurrent%20Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks%20for%20Text%20Classification.pdf) on the document text and the RNN on the title text.

This is pretty ambitious for a beginner, so I suggest you start "simplier" with off-the-shelf-examples of [CNN](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) and [RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) to understand the components and basic concepts of deep learning.